# Which book will discuss torsion tensor and affine connection in detail?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, textbook-recommendation

Which book about differential geometry will have these formula about torsion tensor?

$$\nabla_{j}T^{i}_{kl}+\nabla_{k}T^{i}_{lj}+\nabla_{l}T^{i}_{jk}=R^{i}_{jkl}+R^{i}_{klj}+R^{i}_{ljk}$$

$$\left[\nabla_i, \nabla_j \right]X^k = R^k_{lij}X^l+T^l_{ij}\nabla_l X^k $$

I read many books about differential geometry, but all treat the torsion-free connection.
Which book will discuss the torsion and affine connection in detail and have the formula about 
Bianchi's identity with torsion? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second formula, but with the extra minus sign:
$$\left[\nabla_i, \nabla_j \right]X^k = -R^k_{lij}X^l+T^l_{ij}\nabla_l X^k $$
can be found in  http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/3812 (S.S. Chern, W.H. Chen and K.S. Lam,  Lectures on Differential Geometry) formula 2.46 on page 121. The first identity, I think, is a simple consequence of definitions of R and T tensors through the connection. How the standard geometrical deﬁnitions and formulas are changed under the presence of torsion is explained in http://www.slimy.com/~steuard/teaching/tutorials/GRtorsion.pdf (General Relativity with Torsion: Extending Wald’s Chapter on Curvature, by Steuard Jensen).